# Is there a Sprockets-like library/addon for Spring/SpringMVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, sprockets

I've tried to do this via build tools, but ultimately what I want is something like [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets). Does this exist for Spring/SpringMVC-based projects? Or do I have to write a servlet to do this and cache the result?

Basically, in order to avoid having to maintain development javascript dependency information in the html, and production dependency information in my maven `pom.xml`, I think it would be better to put the dependencies in comments of the actual javascript and css files. This is what Sprockets does.

This kind of solution is better than using a build system because your development and production environments don't need vary anymore - everything is defined in the same spot. You literally don't need to deal with the `pom.xml` anymore, and you don't have to edit your javascript/css tags in your html template anymore.

The problem with making web applications with Java currently is that if you want to minify and aggregate your assets, you end up doing this in Maven or Gradle, which means if you want to test your "live" javascript code that is uncompressed and not aggregated, you have to maintain separate script tags in your layout html template. This is a poor design for maintainability. If you don't want to use live development versions, then you are forced to re-compress and re-aggregate your javascripts/css using maven after EVERY manual edit. This is not a very good way to develop applications, which is why Sprockets is so appealing - it solves this problem by getting it right out of the build system entirely.

I don't need all of the fancy features that Sprockets has. For example, I don't need all the support for engines, like CoffeeScript and SASS. Basic Javascript/css support is fine. I am more interested in getting the compression/aggregation/dependency management features, as well as the timestamp/caching features so that the server doesn't do the compression/aggregating for every page request.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the Sprockets libary you mean.

Comment: @Ralph I added information explaining the problem in more detail

Comment: Okay. I just made my own. Took me 10 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Is [Jawr](http://jawr.java.net/) the thing you are looking for?